# Is electricity constant in standard ECG device?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, biophysics

I am reading the book [*Bioelectromagnetism* by Malmivuo et al.](http://www.bem.fi/book/)

I am thinking if you need to use Maxwell equations in electromagnetism of ECG device.

I am not sure if you need to change the current in the application.

**Is electricity constant in standard ECG device?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by ECG you mean electrocardiogram, then no. You just need very sensitive amplifiers optimized for small signals with plenty of filtering to get rid of unwanted signals. [This is a good description of how to build one and the problems involved.](http://www.realworldengineering.org/download.php?proj=591&file=RWEP_Final1_740_RWEP_Final1_740_ECGAmplifierDesign_BackgroundLecture%5B1%5D.pdf)

Comment: Do you know if you can buy such bioelectrical amplifiers somewhere? I want to test how my own will compete against them.

Comment: You can buy ECG machines on eBay - also EEG machines